# 5 ways to use the static keyword in Java

Tags: java, static, keyword

I just had an interview where one of the questions was something like "Describe 5 ways to use the static keyword in Java."  I could only think of 2 on the spot, and afterwards I found 2 more.  What is the 5th?

1. Declaring a field belonging to a class as opposed to an instance of the class.
2. Declaring a method that can be called on a class as opposed to an instance.
3. Declaring a nested class as static
4. Defining a static class initializer.
5. ???

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "final"? I use that one. :)

Comment: I'm thinking probably not final because I think you can use "final" independently from "static".

Comment: What a crap interview question.  Your ability or otherwise to come up with all five quickly under interview circumstances doesn't really demonstrate Java knowledge IMO.  Not being able to name them all on demand doesn't mean you would be unable to use them effectively in practise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[static import](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5.3) (since java 1.5):

import static my.package.MyClass.*;

Comment: This is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I saw this the day before, but I totally forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Would declaring a `static interface` be considered a class in this instance? If not then there's another use.

Comment: I think it's "Interfaces can do work" per Strange.java by Robert Sedgewick

Answer (score 0):

To change the behaviour of another static method/variable.

Comment: Consider giving examples in order to support your answer (short answers are not indicated)

Answer (score -1):

Constants - static final (which is really the same as #1, but could be consider a separate usage)

Comment: Isn't that the same as "a field belonging to the class"?

Comment: They are the same, but maybe the interviewer considers them different when used in an interface?

Answer (score -1):

create a static block

```
static 
{

 // Do some static work 

}
```

Comment: same as #4 - Defining a static class initializer "block"